# Easy method to populate sub options field on selecting parent option field from database )

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

```
<select><option>tv</option></select> //parent
<select><option>model</option></select> //sub select
```

I want to populate the sub field with TV model or mobile models upon selection from parent

Comment: Look up `<optgroup>` maybe here will help http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: It's called combobox

Comment: You need jQuery and maybe AJAX to do this

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<select id="mySelectTV"><option>tv</option></select> //parent
<select><option>model</option></select> //sub select


var x = document.getElementById("mySelectTV");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "music chanel";
x.add(option);
```

OR using loop

```
var chanels = ['chanel 1', 'chanel 2', 'chanel 3'];
var x = document.getElementById("mySelectTV");
var option = document.createElement("option");
for(var i=0; i< chanels.length; i++){
   option.text = chanels[i] ;
   x.add(option);
}
```

Comment: actually my list is in database like (tv,mobile,printer) upon selecting any of them , i want to fetch values from database containing their models and put it on to the sub select field.